# Difference between {'some_string'} and set('some_string) as key word arguments in Python 3.7+

Tags: python, set

I am giving feedback to a group of students on an assignment, many of whom are attempting to pass a set as a keyword argument in a function by passing a string in curly braces. 
When I print `(type({'some_string'}))` I get class = set. But when I pass the same argument as `set('some_string')` I get different output.

e.g.

```
some_random_function (kwarg = {'some_string'})
```

is different to

```
some_random_funtion(kwarg = set('some_string'))
```

can anyone help me understand why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `{'some_string'}` is different from `set('some_string')`

```
a= set('some_string')
# {'_', 'e', 'g', 'i', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'r', 's', 't'}

a= {'some_string'}
# {some_string'}
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `set` treats its argument as an iterable, and actually **iterated** over your string, creating a set of letters - you'd get the same result from

```
set(['s', 'o', 'm', 'e', '_', 's', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g'])`
```

What you really wanted is `set(['some_string'])`.